# Ajax bringing back JSON and using innerhtml

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, innerhtml

My first attempt at using JSON to bring back my results from my database. I can bring back the results like this:

```
[{"folderName": "Inbox", "MessageType": "AV"},
{"folderName": "Sent", "MessageType": "AV"},
{"folderName": "Deleted", "MessageType": "AV"}]
```

But it doesn't show at all in the browser. I've inspected the elements and there is no li's inside the id=liststart.

```
function showMessages(id) {
    var msgbox = ('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><a href="compose.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-block margin-bottom">Compose</a><div class="box box-solid"><div class="box-header with-border">' +
        '<h3 class="box-title">Folders</h3><div class="box-tools"><button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></div></div><div class="box-body no-padding">' +
        '<ul id="liststart" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"></ul></div></div></div></div>');
    document.getElementById("div_messages").innerHTML = msgbox;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/functiongrabber.asp?loadfunction=getfolders&id=' + encodeURI(id),
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(folderName, function (i, item) {
                var list = ('<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>' + folderName + '<span class="label label-primary pull-right">12</span></a></li>');
                document.getElementById("liststart").innerHTML = list;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you success function you try to iterate over `folderName`, which is not defined, you should be iterating over `data`. Also I think you should be appending the `li`s to the `ul` instead of using innerHTML.

```
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var list = ('<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>' + item.folderName + '<span class="label label-primary pull-right">12</span></a></li>');
            $("#liststart").append(list);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply (and everyone else). Can't seem to get it to work though with any reply. My "msgbox" html doesn't even show on screen, which is weird. It's there when I Inspect Element but nothing when just viewing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over `data` and add to the html each time with:

```
var list;
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    list += ('<li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>' + value.folderName + '<span class="label label-primary pull-right">12</span></a></li>');
})
document.getElementById("liststart").innerHTML = list;
```

This code would go inside the success callback

Comment: Thanks. I get a problem with the "list +=" bit, says "Expecting ','"

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("liststart").innerHTML = list;
```

You are overwriting whatever is in the `<ul>` tag each iteration of `$.each`.

Instead, you should use something like this:

```
var listEl = document.createElement('li');
listEl.innerHTML = list;
document.getElementById('liststart').appendChild(listEl);
```